# Is changing database settings require server restart in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am developing server and database level configuration list to track down the current value and recommend the best practice in order to get a better performance.

And I was wondering if anyone can help me to know that which database level settings require server restart after changing their values.

Comment: You check `select * from sys.configurations`? Anything is_dynamic = 1 does not require a restart.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms189631.aspx) gives a pretty good break down.  Just look under the "Configuration Options Table"

Answer (score 0):

A little dated but it should still apply. :-) Hope this helps!
[SQL Server: What all changes require a restart of SQL Service?](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-what-all-changes-require-a-restart-of-sql-service/)